# How can I find the src of the first img on a page?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm building a web scraper. The piece of code below works, meaning that it actually finds what I'm looking for, which is the main picture (always the first one) in the article.

```
picture = []
for item in body.find_all('img'):
    picture.append(item['src'])
    break
```

Is there a simpler and smoother way to do what I'm doing? I've tried:

```
picture = body.find('img', ['src'])
```

Which just returns "None".

Comment: Like `pictures = [item['src'] for item in body.find_all('img')]`?

Comment: Did you mean: `picture = body.find('img')['src']` ?

Comment: picture = body.find('img')['src'] was the solution I was looking for. Thank you, Jon Clements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
picture_src = body.find('img').attrs['src']

print(picture_src)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
picture = []
for item in body.find_all('img'):
    picture.append(item['src'])
    break
```

Lets work through it.  First off, the "break" is unnecessary.  We can just fall off the end of the 'for' loop.

```
picture = []
for item in body.find_all('img'):
    picture.append(item['src'])
```

Okay, now the Python convention here is to use a list comprehension like Mathias suggested in the comment.

A list comprehension example:

```
doubled = [item * 2 for item in [1, 2, 3, 4]]
print(doubled)
```

Would give:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Compared to Mathias solution:

```
pictures = [item['src'] for item in body.find_all('img')]
```

Note this will fail if there are any img without a src which is also a potential defect in the original solution.

```
pictures = [item['src'] for item in body.find_all('img') if 'src' in item]
```

That is actually more complicated then I usually want a single line to be because reading this code later would require a few seconds to think it through.  Easy fix if you can trust past you:

```
# list of all img src attributes
pictures = [item['src'] for item in body.find_all('img') if 'src' in item]
```